# WiFi without network connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

Recently I've messed with subnetworks setting.
And I did different changes like this

```
sudo ip address del 172.23.99.15/18 dev wlo1
sudo ip address add 172.16.0.0/14 dev wlo1
sudo ip address add 172.20.0.0/15 dev wlo1
sudo ip address add 172.22.0.0/16 dev wlo1
sudo ip address add 172.23.0.0/18 dev wlo1
sudo ip address add 172.23.128.0/17 dev wlo1
sudo ip address add 172.24.0.0/13 dev wlo1
```

Now when I'm trying to connect my PC to the specific router I can't, but my android phone and windows OS can. This problem exists only for the specific router, not for all. Wired connection to this router is also unsuccessful.
This is `ifconfig` output

```
br-43afc9a95225: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        ether 02:42:6c:a5:25:0c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-5d27eab102a4: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.15.255
        ether 02:42:7c:0f:c8:6b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:99:6b:90:2b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether a8:5e:45:bb:0f:3d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2324  bytes 347405 (347.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1337  bytes 150872 (150.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 531902  bytes 94761025 (94.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 531902  bytes 94761025 (94.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.102  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::304a:8cdb:fb84:24b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 28:7f:cf:cc:c3:8d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14302680  bytes 19483030591 (19.4 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7291364  bytes 1292537725 (1.2 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

UPD:
ping 8.8.8.8

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=20 ttl=108 time=2021 ms 
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=21 ttl=108 time=997 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=22 ttl=108 time=6.75 ms 
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=23 ttl=108 time=11.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=24 ttl=108 time=8.50 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=25 ttl=108 time=22.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=26 ttl=108 time=7.93 ms 
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=27 ttl=108 time=10.7 ms
```

Comment: All the changes you did are temporary. So rebooting the PC could fix the problem.

Comment: It's good news that problem wasn't caused by these changes. But I still have no internet connection

Comment: What error do you get, when trying to ping e.g. 8.8.8.8 (google DNS) ?

Comment: I've edited the question to show the ping output

Comment: Sometimes I can send or receive a message from Telegram for example, but I can't connect to websites

Comment: Well the ping on IP is working, so your problem is probably in DNS.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to investigate this